# Springboot case insensitive domain query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I try to retrieve all entities based on a nested entity name. I want this query to be case insensitive. It looks like `LOWER(c.company.companyName)` does not work, since when I type 'abc', but 'ABC' is in a company name somewhere, I still get no result. I've looked all over, but no result. When I remove all the `LOWER` parts, it does work, so for that I'm sure that it has to do with `LOWER(c.company.companyName)`. What am I missing here?

```
@Query(value = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE LOWER(c.company.companyName) LIKE CONCAT('%', LOWER(:search), '%')")
List<Customer> findByCompanyNameContainingIgnoreCase(@Param("search") String search);
```

Answer (score 1):

If getting rid of `@Query` annotation is an option you can just try to use JPA name-derived query like this:

```java
List<Customer> findByCompanyCompanyNameContainingIgnoreCase(String companyName);
```

Spring JPA support for nested objects (property expressions): https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions